# Adding two cells in a double loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying add two cells together and put the result into the first.

[image: Screenshot of the excel sheet]

I created a double loop to go through all the cells and add them together.

I am stuck at how to add the two cells together.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer, p As Integer, r As Integer, v As Integer
' i is for the column in Inventory
' p is for the column in Pending
' r is for the current row
' v is the holding variable for the Sum of both cells

For r = 2 to 30
    For i = 2 To 18

        'This is not proper syntax I think
        Range("AR2").Formula = "=SUM(Cells(r,i),Cells(r,p)"

        v = Range("AR2").Value 'Assigning the value fo he forumla to the variable

        Cells(r, i).ClearContents
        Cells(r, p).ClearContents

        'need to add an if/then statment to clear cell is value is zero
        Cells(r, i).Value = v

        'Do I really need this here cant I add this after the loop?
        Range("AR2").ClearContents 
    Next i
Next r
End Sub
```

I have my comments/questions in the code.

Comment: Don't you mean to increment the row in column AR as well?

Comment: I did not think it would be necessary since I was just using it as a holding Cell for the formula to add the original two cells together. I could not think of a better way to make it work. :(

Comment: you could use `Cells(r, i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(r, i).Value, Cells(r, p).Value)` assigning the formula to AR2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use AR2 as a 'holding cell. Simply retain the value. If you need to use the safety overhead of the worksheet's native [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) (cell values may be text) then use the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) or [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) to facilitate its use.

```
For r = 2 to 30
    For i = 2 To 18
        v = Application.Sum(Cells(r,i), Cells(r,p))

        Cells(r, i).ClearContents
        Cells(r, p).ClearContents

        if cbool(v) then 'v is not zero
            Cells(r, i).Value = v
        end if

    Next i
Next r
```

btw, the original formula was missing a closing bracket and you needed the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx), not the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
Range("AR2").Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(r,i).Address & "," & Cells(r,p).Address & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! I will reach more into the worksheet Function object and Excel Application objects